# HTML-Popup is always shown with controlbar and the thumbstrip when gallery on Highslide is included

Tags: javascript, gallery, highslide

Highslide is an amazing tool, unfortunately i don't get done with my following projekt. I want to show several galleries with Highslide. Therefore i have included 
highslide-full.js and highslide.css.

I have added the modification like in this example:
http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-horizontal-strip+html.html

The gallery works fine: Images with the controlbar and the thumbstrip appear, however the html container appears also with a controlbar - what is my mistake?

EDIT:

One point is now soluted:

The controlbar disappears from the html expand when you apply the correct group for your gallery right here:
slideshowGroup: 'gallery',

The Problem remains that the html expand is still treated like an image in the way of expandation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want HTML expanders to "fade in" rather than zooming in the way image expanders do? If so, just add this to your Highslide JS configuration:

hs.objectLoadTime = 'after';

(This is also much safer for HTML expanders, because it avoids an IE9/IE10 problem that's floating around out there.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have applied your piece of code in the optional addition of link, mentioned above.
Unfortunatelly I didn't get what I expected. Maybe it's better to give you an illusion where my actual problem is:
http://img1.bildupload.com/3cce240e8077ec14baa2e848c09c05b4.jpg
On the left the html iframe how it is supposed to look. But in this option the galleries don't have a controlbar. As soon as I add the controllbar to the code (by adding the proposed code in the linked example) I get wonderfol controlbars in the galleries but the iframe is treated like a img.

Comment: A link to your actual page would be more helpful than a screenshot.

Comment: Just a few minutes. I try to get an example online. Thanks already for your patience and answers.

Comment: http://sv-virnsberg.de/try/testgalerie2.php

I hope this helpful to get my problem. thx!

Comment: You need to define two separate slideshow groups, each with its own settings. Example: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/2galleries-from-text-link.html. In this example, both groups have the same settings. For your case, you would change the config options for the second group so that there's no "number position."

Comment: Great - glad you got it sorted out! RoadRash's collection of sample galleries is a gold mine of information - she's the best. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. One final question: Do I have to add 1000 groups in the header when I want to display 1000 groups (litteraly spoken) or is there a more efficient way to solve this kind of scenario?